# Getting logged out sometimes when switching routes - Heroku Flask_SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, heroku-postgres

My app runs completely fine on my computer (locally), however I'm confused why that is not the case once deployed to Heroku.

When the user registers, I can see all the infos in my Database, but when I try to login I have to try
2-3 times then it works.
Example:

> **I enter my username/password, click login. (Doesn't work)... Then I repeat the same step and it somehow works.
> Also, when I'm logged in, and click somewhere to go to another route, I get disconnected/logged out.**

I'm thinking maybe somehow the app is having issue getting the id of the logged in user.
Any tips would be really appreciated!

What my application.py looks like

```
import sys
import os
import re
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, jsonify
from flask_session import Session
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from werkzeug.exceptions import default_exceptions, HTTPException, InternalServerError
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash
import json
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, and_, desc
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from decimal import Decimal
import urllib.request
import urllib
# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

ENV = ''

if ENV == 'dev':
    app.debug = True # If in Devlopment Mode = True
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/finance'
else:
    app.debug = False
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://databaseurl...'


# Ensure templates are auto-reloaded
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

# Ensure responses aren't cached 
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response


# Custom filter
app.jinja_env.filters["usd"] = usd

# Configure session to use filesystem (instead of signed cookies)
app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#________________ DATABASE models __________________________
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True, nullable=False)
    hash = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    cash = db.Column(db.Numeric, default=10000, nullable=False)
    country = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    def __init__(self, username, hash, email, cash, country):
        self.username = username
        self.hash = hash
        self.email = email
        self.cash = cash
        self.country = country
```

This is my /login route for example;

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    """Log user in"""
    # Forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    # User reached route via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return message("must provide username", 403)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return message("must provide password", 403)

        # Get the input from username field
        username =  request.form.get("username")

        # Query database for that username
        rows = User.query.filter(User.username==username).all()
        # Ensure username exists and password is correct
        if len(rows) != 1 or not check_password_hash(rows[0].hash, request.form.get("password")):
            return message("invalid username and/or password", 403)

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = rows[0].id

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect("/")
```

Comment: your session type is filesystem, probably that is getting cleaned.

Comment: heroku does not deal well with temporary file data.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I learned a lot more thanks to your comment, didn't know heroku didn't deal well with filesystem

Comment: I have to same issue, what did you use instead app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"?